# What does this line in code mean? (array of pointers to chars)?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, size

In this code, the "array" is an array of pointers to chars? Or something else?

```
struct tmep{
    char (*array) [SIZE];
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7):

It's a pointer to an array of `SIZE` `char`s.

Declaration mimics use, so you evaluate the parenthesis first, `(*array)` gives you a `char[SIZE]`.

To allocate, the stable version is as usual

```
array = malloc(num_elements * sizeof *array);
```

to specify the size of each object (`char[SIZE]` here) in the block by taking the `sizeof` the dereferenced pointer. You don't need to change that allocation if the type changes e.g. to `int (*)[SIZE]`.

If you want to specify the type,

```
array = malloc(num_elements * sizeof(char (*)[SIZE]));
```

This allocates - if `malloc` succeeds - a block large enough for `num_elements` arrays of `SIZE` `char`s, each of these arrays is accessed with

```
array[i]
```

and the `char`s in the arrays in the block with

```
array[i][j]
```

Comment: If I want to use malloc in order to allocate that array, with size "ARRAY_SIZE", how should I do so?

Comment: And another question, after allocating the array, I will get an array, that every cell in it is a pointer to an array of char of size SIZE , right ?

Comment: @EliasZarkaNassar: `x.array = malloc(sizeof *x.array);`, where `x` is a `struct tmep`. And check the value returned from `malloc` in case it failed.

Comment: @EliasZarkaNassar: After allocating the array as shown above, you have one array which has `SIZE` elements, and each element is a `char`. If you want `ARRAY_SIZE` arrays of `SIZE` elements of `char`, use `x.array = malloc(ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof *x.array);`.